# Got black color over terrain when I builded for Android on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I upgraded my project from **Unity 2017** to **2019** but when I build again the game for Android I got **black color over terrain**.

I didn't get this problem in Unity 2017.

Things I tried As I read in unity forum I changed Skybox to Color in lighting but nothing fixed my problem. See the images below.

Any help, please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does development build produces any logs about the issue?

Comment: No, I did not get any problem just this wired terrain.

Comment: what shader you use for your terrain?

Comment: Im using simple terrain with simple texture